# python - print squares of numbers which are palindromes : improve efficiency

Tags: python, list, palindrome

I have an assignment to do. The problem is something like this. You give a number, say x. The program calculates the square of the numbers starting from 1 and prints it only if it's a palindrome. The program continues to print such numbers till it reaches the number x provided by you.

I have solved the problem. It works fine for uptil x = 10000000. Works fine as in executes in a reasonable amount of time. I want to improve upon the efficiency of my code. I am open to changing the entire code, if required. My aim is to make a program that could execute 10^20 within around 5 mins.

```
limit = int(input("Enter a number"))
def palindrome(limit):
 count = 1
 base = 1 
 while count < limit:
  base = base * base #square the number
  base = list(str(base)) #convert the number into a list of strings
  rbase = base[:] #make a copy of the number
  rbase.reverse() #reverse this copy
  if len(base) > 1: 
   i = 0
   flag = 1 
   while i < len(base) and flag == 1:
    if base[i] == rbase[i]: #compare the values at the indices
     flag = 1
    else:
     flag = 0
    i += 1
   if flag == 1:
    print(''.join(base)) #print if values match
 base = ''.join(base)
 base = int(base)
 base = count + 1
 count = count + 1
palindrome(limit)
```

Comment: Your program doesn't work for me: _TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'_ at _base = base * base #square the number_.

Comment: No, the indentation is wrong - last four lines of `while` need to be indented to avoid `TypeError`.

Comment: Use 4 spaces for  indentation, your code is hardly readable. And to check whether a number is palindrome, simply this is enough : `str(base)==str(base)[::-1]`.

Comment: sorry for the wrong indentation. It was confusing to copy the code into the text field. I got a better working code. Thanks for all the help guys !

Comment: If you want to make it to 10^20 in 5 minutes, you have to use some mathematical tricks to avoid checking every number. No computer that you will have access to can iterate from 1 to 10^20 in five minutes (even doing nothing in each iteration).

Comment: @nneonneo Oh okay. My teacher's being playful then -_-

Comment: If your teacher wants 1 to 10^20 in 5 minutes, then s/he would be expecting some math tricks. These exist, and will massively speed up your code, but expect it to make for a fairly difficult solution.

Comment: Is the square supposed to be a palindrome, or the number you squared?

Comment: @nneonneo  I added an answer with a maths trick. Please check if it is valid.

Comment: @thefourtheye: it's valid, but doesn't change the fundamental O(...) of the algorithm. You are still having to check every number. (Your `i <= 10000000000000000000` effectively tests every `x` up to 3162277660, which is a very far cry from 10^20).

Comment: @Shonu93: Well, wait, are you going until the *square* is 10^20, or until `x` is 10^20? Because in the first case, you are only going to have to do 10^10 work, which is possible in 5 minutes.

Comment: In any case, I have a time-memory tradeoff in mind that reduces the complexity by O(10^k) at the cost of storing O(10^k) data, for any integer `k`. So if you pick, say, `k = 5`, you can make the algorithm run `10^5` times faster.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://www.worldofnumbers.com/square.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He're my version:

```
import sys

def palindrome(limit):
    for i in range(limit):
        istring = str(i*i)
        if istring == istring[::-1]:
            print(istring,end=" ")
    print()

palindrome(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Timings for your version on my machine:

```
pu@pumbair: ~/Projects/Stackexchange  time python3 palin1.py 100000
121 484 676 10201 12321 14641 40804 44944 69696 94249 698896 1002001 1234321 
4008004 5221225 6948496 100020001 102030201 104060401 121242121 123454321 125686521
400080004 404090404 522808225 617323716 942060249

real    0m0.457s
user    0m0.437s
sys     0m0.012s
```

and for mine:

```
pu@pumbair: ~/Projects/Stackexchange  time python3 palin2.py 100000
0 1 4 9 
121 484 676 10201 12321 14641 40804 44944 69696 94249 698896 1002001 1234321 
4008004 5221225 6948496 100020001 102030201 104060401 121242121 123454321 125686521
400080004 404090404 522808225 617323716 942060249

real    0m0.122s
user    0m0.104s
sys     0m0.010s
```

BTW, my version gives more results (0, 1, 4, 9).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. I too just implemented it a similar way before reading your answer. I too have 0 1 4 9 being outputted. Gotta correct that somehow. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Try running it for a bigger limit.

Answer (score 0):

Surely something like this will perform better (avoiding the unnecessary extra list operations) and is more readable:

```
def palindrome(limit):
  base = 1 
  while base < limit:
    squared = str(base * base)
    reversed = squared[::-1] 
    if squared == reversed:
       print(squared)

    base += 1

limit = int(input("Enter a number: "))
palindrome(limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do it a little bit easier.

```
def palindrome(limit):
    count = 1
    while count < limit:
        base = count * count # square the number
        base = str(base) # convert the number into a string
        rbase = base[::-1] # make a reverse of the string
        if base == rbase:
            print(base) #print if values match
        count += 1

limit = int(input("Enter a number: "))
palindrome(limit)
```

String into number and number into string conversions were unnecessary. Strings can be compared, this is why you shouldn't make a loop.

Comment: `while` loop is still unnecessary.

Comment: Yep. I just wanted to let the old code stay. But `for in` loop is more _pythonic_.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a list of square palindromes upto a certain limit(say L) in memory.If the Input number x is less than sqrt(L) ,you can simply iterate over the list of palindromes and print them.This way you wont have to iterate over every number and check if its square is palindrome .

You can find a list of square palindromes here : http://www.fengyuan.com/palindrome.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my program. It caches valid suffixes for squares (i.e. the values of `n^2 mod 10^k` for a fixed `k`), and then searches for squares which have both that suffix and start with the suffix reversed. This program is very fast: in 24 seconds, it lists all the palindromic squares up to 10^24.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# algorithm will print palindromic squares x**2 up to x = 10**n.
# efficiency is O(max(10**k, n*10**(n-k)))
n = 16
k = 6

cache = defaultdict(list)

print 0, 0 # special case

# Calculate everything up to 10**k; these will be the prefix/suffix pairs we use later
tail = 10**k
for i in xrange(tail):
    if i % 10 == 0: # can't end with 0 and still be a palindrome
        continue
    sq = i*i
    s = str(sq)
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print i, s
    prefix = int(str(sq % tail).zfill(k)[::-1])
    cache[prefix].append(i)

prefixes = sorted(cache)

# Loop through the rest, but only consider matching prefix/suffix pairs
for l in xrange(k*2+1, n*2+1):
    for p in prefixes:
        low = (p * 10**(l-k))**.5
        high = ((p+1) * 10**(l-k))**.5
        low = int(low / tail) * tail
        high = (int(high / tail) + 1) * tail
        for n in xrange(low, high, tail):
            for suf in cache[p]:
                x = n + suf
                s = str(x*x)
                if s == s[::-1]:
                    print x, s
```

Sample output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
11 121
22 484
26 676
101 10201
111 12321
121 14641
202 40804
212 44944
<snip>
111010010111 12323222344844322232321
111100001111 12343210246864201234321
111283619361 12384043938083934048321
112247658961 12599536942224963599521
128817084669 16593841302620314839561
200000000002 40000000000800000000004
```